# GWT future or support is still on

Tags: gwt

My current application is in GWT but discussion going on to migrate it in angular 5.

So just wanted to check if Google team still working on GWT enhancements or still providing the support for GWT?

Answer (score 2):

yes Google is still doing commits on the GWT branch.

No they are not providing support for GWT. But imho they don't provide support for Angular either ?

Comment: And of course j2cl is out now, which can transpile "modern" gwt/java using jsinterop and elemental2 to js.

Comment: There are companies outside Google, that are providing commercial support for GWT.

Comment: OK got it. Thanks.